# Backslash in replace statement - Syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that lets me replace values in my database.

When I use this:

```
$search[] = ("\\");

$sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search[$i].'\',\''.$replace[$i].'\')';
```

I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''\')' at line 1)

I understand its probably just a question of escaping the backslash but Ive tried everything (changing to doublequotes, escaping, using character codes, utf 8 encode/decode etc and still no luck.

Notice that the other values work well (I have a list of $search[] values)

Comment: Please do echo $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = REPLACE('.$field.',\''.$search[$i].'\',\''.$replace[$i].'\')';
exit;
we can see how the query formed.

Comment: As a sidenote, `"UPDATE $table SET $field = REPLACE('$field', '{$search[$i]}', '{$replace[$i]}')";` will be quite easier to read.

Comment: That gives me this: 
Notice:  Undefined offset: 42 in D:\xampp\project\replace.php on line 201



Notice:  Undefined offset: 42 in D:\xampp\project\replace.php on line 201

UPDATE table SET price = REPLACE(price,'','')

Comment: line 42 is: $search[] = ("\\\\");

Comment: Are you doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here at all? This looks like it's full of dangerous SQL injection bugs.

Comment: Yes, and this is for backend on an isolated system anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `"\\"` creates string `\`, therefore plain SQL is `REPLACE('...,\')`, which is an error. Use:

```
$search[] = ("\\\\");
```

Take a look at [mysql string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

Comment: That gives me this error: (ERROR: Got error 'trailing backslash (\)' from regexp)

Comment: Use `echo $sql[$handle]['sql'];` and investigate what SQL is generated, maybe you need escape `\ ` as a part of regex too, therefore you may end up with `$search[] = ("\\\\\\\\");`

Comment: The echo gives me the following value: 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP BINARY('\  ')

Comment: @Woistmeinhandy so do whatever you need to get the right regexp (add escaping).

Comment: Any clue where I should do this ? I have already tried at least 20 different combinations, this is driving me nuts. Thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: @Woistmeinhandy try to write correct query in mysql client (`mysql ....` ; `UPDATE .... `), if you'll have the one that works just force your php code to dump the same string :)

OH and by the way, how much do you know about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
$search[] = ("{\}");
```

That will search for \

or

```
$search[] = ("{\\}");
```

if you want to search for 2 backslashes....

Comment: Hmm actually, this here does not display any error but it doesnt remove the backslash either =/

Comment: @Woistmeinhandy and what about php function stripslashes??? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: @Woistmeinhandy not? well, make sure there are slashes. and what mayby the problem is is that it's converted into html enteties. So you can do this before it...

$field = html_entity_decode($field);

And then run it...